# AWS-Amplify-cli fails to install on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Trying to install AWS-Amplify-CLI and followed [this](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/)

When I run `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` or `sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` I get the following errors

> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@11.8.0 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib'
>   gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/build'
>   gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
>   gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
>   gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents
>   gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>   Failed to execute '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
>   npm WARN graphql-import@0.4.5 requires a peer of graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
>
> - @aws-amplify/cli@0.1.44
>     added 2 packages from 1 contributor, removed 6 packages and updated 29 packages in 57.461s

When I install `node-pre-gyp` and `node-gyp` separately, I get the same errors.

I have `CHMOD 0777` on the project folder and then tried to install again without the -g flag, but same error.

OS: Mojave 10.14.2
Node: v11.8.0
npm: 6.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

It seems that there was an issue with my global installation of node and npm, missing/incorrect entries in:

- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc

The fix was to totally remove node & npm, the re-install using nvm. I followed these:

- https://github.com/brock/node-reinstall/
- https://gist.github.com/d2s/372b5943bce17b964a79

Please note:

- you may need to remove some node or npm files manually
- you may need to upgrade node and/or npm afterwards
- you may need to reinstall individual node packages afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

You may also try the following command that worked for me :

```
sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I needed to set the python version for some odd reason. Something like 
npm config set python python2.7 && npm install

Amplify needs local resources and needs to be tied to a environment especially if you are switching between them.

Like dev/prod or local dev on a Mac vs some dev in windows.

Look at amplify env add

Answer (score 1):

EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally

- First uninstall amplify

> npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli

- or

> sudo amplify uninstall

- Reinstall npm with a node version manager, I recommend this guide https://tecadmin.net/install-nvm-macos-with-homebrew/
- On command line create a directory for global installations

> mkdir ~/.npm-global

- Configure npm to use the new directory path:

> npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

- For versions after MacOS Catalina uses **nano ~/.zshrc** and for versions before this version uses **nano ~/.profile** and add the next line

> export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

- On the command line, update your system variables. **If you used ~/. zshrc**

> source ~/.zshrc

- **If you used ~/. profile**

> source ~/.profile

- Then try to install amplify

> npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli

Answer (score 0):

I had node installed via brew so my fix was:

1. uninstall node completely

   brew uninstall --force node
2. install node via: https://nodejs.org/es/ which updates PATH automatically
3. install amplify:

   sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve this:

1. Re-install `node` to the latest version. You can do that using the following steps:

> ```
> - sudo npm cache clean -f (force) clear you npm cache
> - sudo npm install -g n install n (this might take a while)
> - sudo n stable upgrade to the current stable version
> ```

Note that sudo might prompt your password.

2. Install `amplify`:

> sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true

This last process may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted solution seemed to work initially, I encountered further `EACCES: permission error` while using amplify-cli. The way I got it solved is by resolving `EACESS permissions` as recommended by [npmjs documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

**Instructions:**

1. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
nano ~/.profile
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

4. On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

5. Test if the added path is working by looking for the string `.npm-global/bin` in the outpout:

```
echo $PATH
```

6. Finally, install aws-amplify/cli without using sudo as follows:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

The available commands have been updated. If you type 'aws amplify help' in your terminal you will get an output that shows the available commands:

NAME
amplify -

DESCRIPTION
Amplify  enables  developers to develop and deploy cloud-powered mobile
and web apps. The Amplify Console provides a  continuous  delivery  and
hosting  service  for  web  applications. For more information, see the
Amplify Console User Guide . The Amplify Framework is  a  comprehensive
set  of SDKs, libraries, tools, and documentation for client app devel-
opment. For more information, see the Amplify Framework.

AVAILABLE COMMANDS
o create-app

```
   o create-backend-environment

   o create-branch

   o create-deployment

   o create-domain-association

   o create-webhook

   o delete-app

   o delete-backend-environment...
```

And etc.